# Elasticsearch bulk upsert with query on specific field

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

There is an index with this mapping:

```json
"data": {
   "type": "object"
},
"modified_date": {
   "type": "date"
},
"uid": {
   "type": "keyword"
}
```

Now I want to do a bulk operation for **upsert** (Update if exists and insert if not exists). The query is on `uid` field. I wrote this query but its not working.

```json
URL : http://host/index/_bulk
METHOD : POST
DATA :
{"update":{"uid":"123"}}
{"doc":{"modified_date":"...", "data":{"array":[1,2,3]}}, "doc_as_upsert":true}
{"update":{"uid":"456"}}
{"doc":{"modified_date":"...", "data":{"array":[4,5,6]}}, "doc_as_upsert":true}
{"update":{"uid":"789"}}
{"doc":{"modified_date":"...", "data":{"array":[7,8,9]}}, "doc_as_upsert":true}
```

How can I do bulk upsert with query on `uid` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider querying the `_id` field directly instead of `uid` field.

Answer (score -1):

If you change operation from `update` to `insert`, you'd be upserting.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

> The index and create actions expect a source on the next line, and have the same semantics as the op_type parameter in the standard index API: create fails if a document with the same ID already exists in the target, **index adds or replaces a document as necessary.**

Comment: Downvoted because "update" and "replace" are different things.